# Leibniz's Law in Suppes's 'Introduction to Logic'

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I've been reading Patrick Suppes's book 'Introduction to Logic'. In chapter 5 of the book he introduces a reader to the **Leibniz's law** or **the principle of the indentity of indiscernibles**. He provides a definition and a small proof for this principle. The definion looks incomplete although the proof seems to be valid. Here's a paragraph from the book:

> If every property of *x* is also a property of $y$, then *x = y*; for *x* has the property of being identical with *x*, and hence if every property of *x* is a property of *y*, then *y* has the property of being identical with *x*, so that *y = x*, and hence *x = y*.

If we assume that $y$ has all properties that $x$ has and an additional one which $x$ doesn't possess. Using the definition above we can infer that $x = y$ but $y \ne x$. This contradicts the reflective property of equivalence relation.

In my opinion the valid definition should look like this:

> 'If every property of $x$ is also a property of $y$ AND if every property of $y$ is also a property of $x$ then $x = y$.'

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Identity of Indiscernibles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/#Form):

> the principle is usually formulated as follows: if, for every property $F$, object $x$ has $F$ if and only if object $y$ has $F$, then $x$ is *identical* to $y$. Or in the notation of symbolic logic [not *first-order*]:
>
> > $∀F \ (Fx ↔ Fy) → x=y$.

Your suggested formulation:

> If every property of $x$ is also a property of $y$ AND if every property of $y$ is also a property of $x$,

is correct. It is formalized with the bi-conditional: $\leftrightarrow$.

---

Suppes' formulation amounts to:

> $∀F \ (Fx \to Fy) → x=y$.

Suppes' heuristic reasoning is the following:

> Granted the previous stated laws: *reflexivity*: $x=x$ (called *law of identity*), *simmetry*: $x=y \to y=x$ and *transitivity*:
>
> > assume that every property of $x$ is also a property of $y$. Then $x$ has the property of being identical with $x$ (*reflexivity*), and hence if every property of $x$ is a property of $y$, then $y$ has the property of being identical with $x$, so that $y = x$.
>
> But then, by *symmetry*: $x = y$.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question. The OP asked about an apparent problem with the formulation in Suppes, and this doesn't say anything about that as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we assume that $y$ has every property possessed by $x$ and also a property that $x$ does not have that leads to a contradiction. It does not follow that we need to change Leibniz - all that follows is that our assumption was *false*.

Answer (score 0):

There's another property that's a converse to the identity of indiscernibles called the [indiscernibility of identicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles#Identity_and_indiscernibility): $$\forall x,y.(x = y)\land P(x) \implies P(y)$$
This and reflexivity is often taken as defining equality. On the linked Wikipedia page, it gives a derivation of symmetry and transitivity from these. This is often presented as a rule of inference for equality rather than an axiom which avoids needing second-order logic.

This principle states that if $x = y$, then any property of $x$ is also a property of $y$ (and by the derived symmetry, vice versa). As David C. Ullrich states, you've simply assumed something contradictory (that $y$ has an additional property that $x$ does not) and derived a contradiction from it.